# Hide input variables popping up in indicator settings in Pine

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to create a meta indicator with several indicators combined and have several inputs in my code. Is there a way to hide all input variables from indicator settings so as it doesnt pop out on my screen when i use my indicator?

[image: Screenshot of my indicator in use]

I want to hide all these input variables so as to declutter my screen but dont know if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uncheck "Arguments" in chart settings, in Status line section:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Moebius - It was so simple! Much appreciate it.